# Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1)

Tags: android, build.gradle

I was downloading Android Studio 3.5 .. and I got this error saying ::

***ERROR: Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1). Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.jar***

I checked some solutions about adding **google()** repo to the build.gradle and it was already there

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
                  }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
                 }
            }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
                 }
            }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
        }
```

no ""offline work"" checked in global gradle setting

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and this method has solved my problem
Please follow the below steps:

- Download gradle.jar from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.jar
- Close your android studio project
- Close android studio
- Remove > C:\Users\your user\ .gradle directory
- Open your project
- Make sure you are connect with internet
- Sync your project